# AWK scripting to to find highest number

Tags: awk, scripting

```
1. \#id;clientid;product name;qty;price
1. 1;fooclient;product A;3;100
2. 2;booclient;product B;4;200
1. 3;xyzzycompany;product C;2;35000
1. 4;testclient;product B;1;190
1. 5;fooclient;product A;10;100
1. 6;testclient;product B;1;25000
1. 7;Mouccccccc;product C;2;300
1. 8;Deeccccccc;product C;2;10
1. 9;ICICT;product Z;12;45000
1. 10;AXISX;product D;14;75000
1. 11;Fcebook;product Z;12;65000
```

Need help to find highest price having clientid name using awk.

Options tried: 
filename: invoices_input.txt [having all above mentioned values]

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ";" } !/^#/ {print $2 " " $NF}' invoices_input.txt
```

Result:

```
fooclient 100
booclient 200
xyzzycompany 35000
testclient 190
fooclient 100
testclient 25000
Mouccccccc 300
Deeccccccc 10
ICICT 45000
AXISX 75000
Fcebook 65000
```

I am expecting **AXISX** to printed as highest numbered client.

Comment: Gave a try with 
awk  -F';' 'NR==1{max = $NF + 0; next} {if ($NF > max) max = $NF;} END {print max}' invoices_input.txt
75000

which resulted highest number, but i am expecting the clientID not number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F\; 'NR > 1 {
  if ($5 > price) {
    price = $5
    company = $2
  }
  else if ($5 == price) {
    company = company "\n" $2
  }
}
END { 
  print company
}' file
```

Comment: > XXXXX ~ $ awk -F\; '{if($5> price){price=$5;company=$2}}END{print company}' invoices_input.txt
> clientid
> XXXXX ~ $ cat invoices_input.txt

>  \#id;clientid;product name;qty;price
> 1;fooclient;product A;3;100
> 2;booclient;product B;4;200
> 3;xyzzycompany;product C;2;35000
> 4;testclient;product B;1;190
> 5;fooclient;product A;10;100
> 6;testclient;product B;1;25000
> 7;Mouccccccc;product C;2;300
> 8;Deeccccccc;product C;2;10
> 9;ICICT;product Z;12;45000
> 10;AXISX;product D;14;75000
> 11;Fcebook;product Z;12;65000

Comment: Its not resulting as expected; it is just printing the clientid in first line. But awk script should look for highest values entry and print the clientid entry. Hoping it helps to understand what i am struggling with :(

Comment: The output is in the file you wrote it to.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks it worked. If we have same highest numbers for 2 clients, seems script is taking only first match. If we want to print all clientID's where we have same highest number, is there any condition to adjust?

Comment: Not your down-voter (yet), but code-only answers are often considered "low-quality" as they help only the OP (original poster) but don't provide much help to future visitors to the site with similar problems, the prime purpose of this site. Please do consider editing the answer, providing decent textual explanation of the answer.

Comment: but the code is clear enough to be understood by anyone who is familiar with programming.

Comment: All I'm saying is that explanations are highly valued here. Up to you what you want to do

Comment: It is true the code is transparent and well-indented, it is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

with `awk` and friends

```
$ sort -t';' -k2,2 -k5,5nr file              | 
  awk -F';' '!a[$2]++{print $1 "\t" $2,$NF}' | 
  sort -n                                    | 
  cut -f2-

clientid price
fooclient 100
AXISX 75000
Fcebook 65000
booclient 200
xyzzycompany 35000
testclient 25000
Mouccccccc 300
Deeccccccc 10
ICICT 45000
```

of course you can do all in `awk` as well.

without maintaining the order (assumes prices>0)

```
$ awk -F';' 'a[$2]<$NF {a[$2]=$NF} 
             END       {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file

clientid price
fooclient 100
ICICT 45000
Deeccccccc 10
xyzzycompany 35000
Fcebook 65000
testclient 25000
booclient 200
Mouccccccc 300
AXISX 75000
```

If you just need the client with highest price you don't need all this complexity

```
$ sort -t';' -k5,5nr file | sed 1q | cut -d';' -f2
AXISX
```

Comment: But i just wanted to get **AXISX 75000**, that too, it should print only clientID **AXISX**, it can ignore number.